# How to reduce initial load of polyfills script in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, pagespeed, polyfills

I'm trying to reduce page initial load of my angular (Angular 6) app. I've already lazy load modules, minify js and css, add "--prod --build-optimizer --aot" tag to my build script but not found any solutions to reduce "polyfills" script execution time.
I use "Chrome Audits" tools to see page performance.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One other thing you can do is use  --vendorChunk=true|false argument in the ng build.
This will create a separate bundle containing only vendor libraries.

```
e.g. "ng build --prod --buildOptimizer --aot --vendorChunk"
```

Reference: https://angular.io/cli/build

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth looking into Angular 8s soon-to-be released 'differential loading' feature. This will enable loading only those polyfills that are necessary for the users specific browser (which for most modern evergreen browsers will mean: very few.)

Until it is released, here's an article (one of many) on that topic: https://dev.to/lacolaco/differential-loading-a-new-feature-of-angular-cli-v8-4jl